# android app to select a file from sdcard and upload to server using socket

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to develop an android app that can upload a file from the phone to my laptop. I have two activities:

1. SimpleClientActivity
2. File chooser activity

I am trying to browse the file in Filechooser activity and pass the file directory via putExtra and getExtra but it fails to upload. However if I hard-code the file directory it will successfully upload the file.

Here is the code. Please elaborate your answer since I am a beginner.

Simple Client Activity

```
public class SlimpleTextClientActivity extends Activity {

public Socket client;
public PrintWriter printwriter;
public EditText textField;
public Button button1,button2;
public String messsage;
public  String file_path;
public int count=1;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_slimple_text_client);

    textField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1); // reference to the text field
    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1); // reference to the filechoosing button
    button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);//reference to send button
    // Button press event listener
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

       public void onClick(View v) {

           Intent i = new Intent(SlimpleTextClientActivity.this, FileChooser.class);
           startActivity(i);
           Intent intent=getIntent();
           String directory1;
           Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
           try {
               directory1 = b.getString("directory");
               file_path = directory1;
           } catch (Exception e) {

               textField.setText(e.getMessage());
               directory1="returned nothon";
           }

           if (file_path == null) {
               file_path = "no file choosen";
           }

          textField.setText(directory1);
       }
                               }

    );
   button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

   public void onClick(View v) {

      SendMessage sendMessageTask = new SendMessage();
      sendMessageTask.execute();


   }
   }
    );


}
private class SendMessage extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private FileInputStream fileInputStream;
    private BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream;
    private OutputStream outputStream;
    private Button button;


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        Socket socket;
        try
        {int count=0;
            socket = new Socket("192.168.137.1", 4444);
            if(!socket.isConnected())
                textField.setText("Socket Connection Not established");
            else
                System.out.println("Socket Connection established : "+socket.getInetAddress()); File myfile = new File(file_path);
   //local file path.
            if(!myfile.exists())
                System.out.println("File Not Existing.");
            else
                System.out.println("File Existing.");

            byte[] byteArray = new byte[100];

            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myfile);
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
            OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
            int trxBytes =0;
            while((trxBytes = bis.read(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length)) !=-1)
            {
                os.write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
                System.out.println("Transfering bytes : "+trxBytes );
            }
            os.flush();
            bis.close();
            socket.close();

            System.out.println("File Transfered...");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Client Exception : "+e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }
}
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu){
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_slimple_text_client, menu);
        return true;
    }
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    // Check if the key event was the Back button and if there's history
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                this);

        // set title
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Dude are you serious???");

        // set dialog message
        alertDialogBuilder
                .setMessage("Do you want to quit??")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        SlimpleTextClientActivity.this.finish();


                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        // if this button is clicked, just close
                        // the dialog box and do nothing
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

        // create alert dialog
        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

        // show it
        alertDialog.show();

        //super.onBackPressed();

        // return true;
    }
    return false;
}}
```

2.FileChooser activity

```
public class FileChooser extends ListActivity {
//Intent intentchooser=getIntent();
public String directory;
private List<String> item = null;
private List<String> path = null;
private String root;
private TextView myPath;
public EditText textField;
final Context context = this;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.file);
   myPath = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.path);
  //   textField=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.small);
    root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
    getDir(root);
}
public File f;
private void getDir(String dirPath)
{
    myPath.setText("Location: " + dirPath);
    item = new ArrayList<String>();
    path = new ArrayList<String>();
    f = new File(dirPath);
   File[] files = f.listFiles();
    if(!dirPath.equals(root))
    {
        item.add(root);
        path.add(root);
        item.add("../");
        path.add(f.getParent());
    }
    for(int i=0; i < files.length; i++)
    {
        File file = files[i];

        if(!file.isHidden() && file.canRead()){
            path.add(file.getPath());
            if(file.isDirectory()){
                item.add(file.getName() + "/");
            }else{
                item.add(file.getName());
            }
        }
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> fileList =
            new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.row, item);
    setListAdapter(fileList);
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    File file = new File(path.get(position));
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            context);
    if (file.isDirectory())
    {
        if(file.canRead()){
            getDir(path.get(position));

        }else{
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setTitle("[" + file.getName() + "] folder can't be     read!")
                    .setPositiveButton("OK", null).show();

           // this.finish();
        }
    }else {
       final File filetemp=file;
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                context);

        // set title
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Ready to upload???");

        // set dialog message
        alertDialogBuilder1
                .setMessage("Do you want upload??")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("OK",new    DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                        // if this button is clicked, close
                        // current activity
                        FileChooser.this.finish();
                        Intent in=new    Intent(FileChooser.this,SlimpleTextClientActivity.class);
                        in.putExtra("directory",filetemp.getAbsolutePath());
                             System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\n\n"+filetemp.getAbsolutePath()+"\n\n\n\n\n");
                       // textField.setText(filetemp.getAbsolutePath());

                        startActivity(in);


                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("No",new   DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                        // if this button is clicked, just close
                        // the dialog box and do nothing
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

        // create alert dialog        
AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder1.create();

          // show it
        alertDialog.show();
        textField.setText("file.getAbsolutePath()");
        Intent in=new Intent(FileChooser.this,SlimpleTextClientActivity.class);


        startActivity(in);

       finish();
    }
}
 public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
 {
    // Check if the key event was the Back button and if there's history
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK))
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = ne`enter code here`w    AlertDialog.Builder(
                context);
// set title
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Dude are you serious???");

        // set dialog message
        alertDialogBuilder
                .setMessage("Do you want to cancel file uploading??")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes",new   DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                        // if this button is clicked, close
                        // current activity
                      FileChooser.this.finish();
                        Intent in=new   Intent(FileChooser.this,SlimpleTextClientActivity.class);
                        in.putExtra("directory","yo baby ");

                        startActivity(in);


                    }
                  })
                  .setNegativeButton("No",new   DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                        // if this button is clicked, just close
                        // the dialog box and do nothing
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

        // create alert dialog
        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

        // show it
        alertDialog.show();

        //super.onBackPressed();


        // return true;
    }
     return false;
}
}
```

This is where the app crashes  if i dont handle the exception

```
  try {
               directory1 = b.getString("directory");
               file_path = directory1;
           } catch (Exception e) {
               textField.setText(e.getMessage());
               directory1="returned nothin";
           }
```

Here is my xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="shiva.com.filesenderlakj;"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" >
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" >
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" >
</uses-permission>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="shiva.com.filesenderlakj.SlimpleTextClientActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="shiva.com.filesenderlakj.FileChooser"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: What kind of failure do you get? Is there an error?

Comment: To follow on what Sebastiaan asked for, can you also provide your Android.xml file and the hard-coded path that works for you?

Comment: @SebastiaanvandenBroek:in button1 onclicklistener  try {
               directory1 = b.getString("directory");
               file_path = directory1;
           } catch (Exception e) {

               textField.setText(e.getMessage());
               directory1="returned nothin";
           }  if i don't use catch block, the app automatically crashes , if i use the catch block, exception is caught and variable directory is initialized to " returned nonthin"

Comment: Can you edit that into your question? It's a bit hard to read like this. But you will probably want to include what the exception message is.

Comment: @justhecuke: In the SlimpleClient Activity in the doInBackground method, after verifying that the socket is connected, if i use File myfile=new File("/storage/sdcard/ip.txt"); it works,  however File myfile=new File(file_path); doesn't work, file_path is a string for which the value is loaded using getExtra() method

Comment: @SebastiaanvandenBroek: Yes, if i dont include that exception, the app crashes.

Comment: I meant to include in your post here what the message of the exception is.

Comment: @SebastiaanvandenBroek:  It says NULLPOINTER exception in that. It shows the message "UNFORTUNATELY APP IS STOPPED" yet it starts second activity in Emulator, in my phone app simply crashes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your code throws an exception in here

```
try {
    directory1 = b.getString("directory");
    file_path = directory1;
} catch (Exception e) {
    textField.setText(e.getMessage());
    directory1="returned nothon";
}
```

That implies that you don't have a `"directory"` extra in your intent.

When you start `SimpleClientActivity`, you need to make sure that you use an intent with the `"directory"`extra.

EDIT: I've looked at your code a bit more and have an architectural suggestion. You should not be using startActivity since you are doing Client -> Chooser -> Client. startActivity is good for non-cycle activity starting. You should look into using a BroadcastReceiver or a LocalBroadcastManager if you want to be more correct.

DISCLAIMER: I typed up this code without compiling or doing any sort of checking. This is only meant to guide you in how to integrate the "proper" way of doing things into your app.

To make a BroadcastReceiver, you do something like:

```
BroadcastReceiver br = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle b = intent.getExtras();
        if (b.hasExtra(DIRECTORY_EXTRA)) {
            textField.setText(b.getString(DIRECTORY_EXTRA));
        }
    }
}
```

What this does is when your BroadcastReceiver receives an intent, onReceived() will be called with the context in which the receiver was running and the intent that it received.

To get the BroadcastReceiver set up to receive intents, you need to register it for a particular kind of intent using an intent filter:

```
IntentFilter myIntentFilter = new IntentFilter("my.app.package.myintent");
```

You can then pair a BrodacastReceiver with an IntentFilter to tell the Android OS to forward an intent to you when it gets sent an intent broadcast.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // <make the BroadcastReceiver>
    // <make the intent filter>
    registerReceiver (br, myIntentFilter);
}
```

Now, instead of doing startActivity to communicate, you can use sendBroadcast.

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent("my.app.package.myintent");
myIntent.putExtra(DIRECTORY_EXTRA, directoryString);
sendBroadcast(myIntent);
```

Comment: Hey there is "directory" key in the second activity, i have used in.putExtra("directory",file.getAbsolutePath());    The same code works if I start third activity(new activity) from my second activity  instead of switching back to the first activity.

Comment: If you get a Null Pointer Exception when trying to call b.getString("directory") then (b == null) must be true. This means that the intent that you received does not have extras. Please review my answer again. Since you are a beginner, I will provide more context so you can arrive at a solution.